# Flashing folder at start up, all recommended troubleshooting has failed

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, install

I really hope someone might be able to help with this cause I am getting frustrated beyond belief.

I have a MacBook Pro with Mavericks OS X 10.9. About a week ago it crashed while I was printing, first my desktop went gray while still displaying my desktop folders and froze. I manually shut it off and upon restart I got the flashing folder with a question mark.

so far my steps have been:

Holding shift at start up - the screen stays grey and freezes (doesn't even get as far as the flashing folder)

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - continues into internet recovery mode

disk utility - Disk0 and mac OS X base system are available

- under base system / first aid / verify disk - I get an all green and no repairs are needed
- under erase and restore - all options are grayed out

when closing out of the OS X Utilities window and going into start up disk - no disk is available

Reinstall OS X - I am able to get though licensing agreement and then it stops on selecting the disk to install on because no disk options show up and there is no searching indicator or failed message.

I have taken my hard drive out and placed it in an enclosure where I was able to access and copy the files through the USB on an older laptop that is running Snow Leopard.

As far as I can tell, my hard drive is fine, all the files were available, there are no strange sounds while it is spinning and I am completely at a loss. Please help.

*** EDIT: troubleshooting also includes:

- holding <kbd>D</kbd> during start up and running the extensive hardware test. No problems were detected.
- holding command + option + P + R during start up until the starting sound plays twice to reset NVRAM. It went right back to the flashing folder
- holding command + S at start up for single-user mode and my laptop doesn't register, it goes straight back to the flashing folder (same with just holding S, though when I looked it up, everywhere else advised command + S).

Since I am unable to do anything productive in disk utility, is there anything else that anyone thinks might work?

Answer (score 2):

Hate to say it, buddy, but if disk0 and base system are all you got, and if base system is part of disk0, your MacBook Pro isn't seeing your hard drive. Reset the SMC if you can (Shift+Control+Option+Power while plugged in, then press power again after releasing all keys.) But if that doesn't work, it's either the SATA controller, the connection to the drive, or the drive. At that point, it's a store visit.

Comment: well crud, looks like a store visit it is then, cause resetting the SMC didn't work either. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

For future reference incase anyone else hits this issue, I took the laptop in and the resolution is mechanical. The hard drive cable has to be replaced. Also, if anyone is more comfortable than I am with breaking into the guts of your laptop, that part is roughly $30.00

Thank you everyone for your help!